# WiX automatic file inclusion

Tags: wix, paraffin

Is there a way to include files automatically based on directory structure?

I do not want to add each and every file name with file Id tab.

My build process create the required directory structure:

```
ProductName
           Directory1
           Directory2
           Directory3
           Directory4
```

How can I add those directories and their subdirectories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not automatically. There are some tools however (called "tallow" for Wix" or "heat" for Wix3) that will scan a directory and create a Wix fragment (a separate WiX *.wxs file) for you. You can then compile that "filelist.wxs" file (or whatever you call it) into your WiX install.

See this page for the [WiX3 heat documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm) and there should also be a WiX2 equivalent for tallow on that site.

Marc

Answer (score 16):

There is also [Paraffin](https://github.com/Wintellect/Paraffin) by [John Robbins](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins). It has some nice features:

> My goal for PARAFFIN.EXE was that it would build immediately consumable WiX fragments with a minimum of fuss on your part. I wanted PARAFFIN.EXE to meet the following requirements for initially creating a .WXS fragment for a directory:
>
> - PARRAFIN.EXE created unique values to the Component, Directory, and File elements Id attribute so you do not have to worry about conflicts across large projects
> - PARAFIN.EXE creates a ComponentGroup element in the output file with all Component elements in the file automatically specified with ComponentRef values
> - You can optionally exclude specific file extensions from being added to the .WXS fragment
> - You can optionally exclude directories from inclusion by specifying a partial name
> - You can optionally specify if you want GUID values automatically generated for all components
> - You can optionally specify multiple files per Component (the default is one file per component)
> - You can optionally specify that you do not want to recurse directories other than the one specified
> - You can optionally specify an alias for the directory name when setting the File element - - Source attribute so you do not have hard coded drive and directory names in the output .WXS file
>
> After you've created a .WXS fragment with PARAFFIN.EXE, you don't want to have to edit the fragment manually, so I wanted PARAFFIN.EXE to meet the following requirements for creating an updated output file from an existing .WXS fragment:
>
> - The updated output is written to a .PARAFFIN file so the original .WXS fragment is not disturbed
> - All command line options specified when creating the initial .WXS fragment are automatically set when updating a file created by PARAFFIN.EXE
> - Any new directories and files found are automatically added to the output file
> - Any directories and files that are no longer part of the directory structure are removed from the output file

Comment: Link to [Parrafin](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/12/22/paraffin-3-0-now-with-full-wix-3-0-support.aspx) is broken - I am getting a **404 error.** Do you know if that tool still exists?